# Amazon Redshift COPY always return S3ServiceException:Access Denied,Status 403

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I'm really struggling with how to do data transfer from Amazon S3 bucket to Redshift with COPY command.

So far, I created an IAM User and 'AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess' policy is assigned. But when I call COPY command likes following, Access Denied Error is always returned.

> copy my_table from 's3://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/myobject' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<...>;aws_secret_access_key=<...>' REGION'ap-northeast-2' delimiter '|';

Error:

> Amazon Invalid operation: S3ServiceException:Access Denied,Status 403,Error AccessDenied,Rid EB18FDE35E1E0CAB,ExtRid ,CanRetry 1 
>   Details: -----------------------------------------------
>     error:  S3ServiceException:Access Denied,Status 403,Error AccessDenied,Rid EB18FDE35E1E0CAB,ExtRid ,CanRetry 1
>     code:      8001
>     context:   Listing bucket=s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com prefix=mybucket/myobject
>     query:     1311463
>     location:  s3_utility.cpp:542
>     process:   padbmaster [pid=4527]
>     -----------------------------------------------;

Is there anyone can give me some clues or advice?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the endpoint `s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com` from the S3 path:

```
COPY my_table
FROM 's3://mybucket/myobject'
CREDENTIALS ''
REGION 'ap-northeast-2'
DELIMITER '|'
;
```

(See the [examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-source-s3.html#copy-parameters-data-source-s3-examples) in the documentation.) While the `Access Denied` error is definitely misleading, the returned message gives some hint as to what went wrong:

```
bucket=s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com
prefix=mybucket/myobject
```

We'd expect to see `bucket=mybucket` and `prefix=myobject`, though.

Comment: Thank you so much!! You ' re so helpful!

Answer (score 0):

My Scenario (Cross Account):
***Account B Lambda was trying to access Redshift and S3 in Account A.***

My Redshift Cluster was publicly availble and I created the connection using redshift credentials (e.g. host, port, username, etc).

All other queries were executed except this COPY command.
Later I find out that this COPY command is trying to fetch the file from S3 bucket over the internet and **my S3 bucket is not accessible over the internet**.

Then I changed the COPY command using the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-access-permissions.html#copy-usage_notes-iam-permissions):
Removed the IAM role and provided credentials using this syntax:

```
copy table-name
from 's3://objectpath'
access_key_id '<temporary-access-key-id>'
secret_access_key '<temporary-secret-access-key>'
session_token '<temporary-token>';
```

> **Note:** `session_token` is only required when you obtained the creds from
> STS by assuming a role. If you're providing hard coded credentials or manually generated creds you don't need `session_token`

Answer (score -1):

1. Check encription of bucket.

According doc : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/c_loading-encrypted-files.html
The COPY command automatically recognizes and loads files encrypted using SSE-S3 and SSE-KMS.

2. Check kms: rules on you key|role
3. If files from EMR, check Security configurations for S3.

Answer (score -2):

your redshift cluster role does not have right to access to the S3 bucket. make sure the role you use for redshift has access to the bucket and bucket does not have policy that blocks the access